# How to skip cucumber tests with parsing error in maven?

Tags: maven, cucumber, integration-testing, pom.xml, maven-failsafe-plugin

I run my cucumber tests by using `mvn integration-test`. If my test directory contains test which ends with `Error parsing feature file`, my next tests do not run at all.

I've got 4 .feature files, one of them contain invalid step (not parsed). If I remove that step, I have a successfull run for 4 files (`Tests run: 23, Failures: 2, Errors: 0, Skipped: 3` ),

if I don't, I've got the following message: `Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.078 sec <<< FAILURE!`. I want maven to continue testing after 1 invalid feature file, not to stop on the first one, so I need something like `Tests run: 24, Failures: 2, Errors: 1, Skipped: 3` (my unparseable step is the last one)

Fragment of my pom.xml:

```
                    <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.18.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                <goal>verify</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <cucumber.options>${cucumber.options}</cucumber.options>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

**Question**: How can I make maven continue with other cucumber features after the error?

Comment: can you please share the relevant part of your `pom.xml` file?

Comment: Put a ignore tag on the feature file. And filter out the ignore tag using negation in your runner. tags = {"~@ignore"}. If you have any other tags make this 'not ignore' tag an AND condition.

Comment: Thanks @Grasshopper for your comment, but I don't want to put any tags on it, I need maven just to mark the test as error and continue working.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot skip only parsings errors, there is no knowledge of the type of error for the test execution.

However, based on your experience you may get a certain number of acceptable failures (to keep testing till the end your test suite or till a certain acceptable failures rate) using the [`skipAfterFailureCount`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#skipAfterFailureCount) option of the `maven-failsafe-plugin` (the `maven-surefire-plugin` has the [same](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#skipAfterFailureCount) option in case you are using it).

Alternatively, and with a more strong approach, you may set the Maven build to ignore failures during tests and keep on testing the whole suite by using the [`testFailureIgnore`](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/verify-mojo.html#testFailureIgnore) of the `maven-failsafe-plugin` for its `verify` goal or the [same](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#testFailureIgnore) option for the `maven-surefire-plugin`.

If you don't want to configure them in your `pom.xml` as default build, you could delegate this behavior to a [maven profile](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) or use their respective command line options:

```
mvn clean verify -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true
```

Or (to use the first option above)

```
mvn clean verify -Dsurefire.skipAfterFailureCount=42
```

Or (depending on the plugin you used)

```
mvn clean verify -Dfailsafe.skipAfterFailureCount=12
```

---

Note that I used `verify` and not `integration-test` as a phase because integration tests are supposed to set-up and tear down a context/env to integrate against, to properly execute integration tests in this case you should:

- Use the `maven-failsafe-plugin` and not the `maven-surefire-plugin`
- Use the `pre-integration-test,`integration-test`and`post-integration-test` to properly set-up, execute, clean your integration test phase

Comment: Thanks. I used failsafe plugin, unfortunately, this didn't help me. I edited the question, added more details.

Comment: @БогданТимофеев did you try adding to the `configuration` of your failsafe declaration the option mentioned in this answer, `testFailureIgnore` to `true` and check whether that would meet your requirements or not?